# How to select first child of parent by using ID of a child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to select the `td` element which contains "Text1" without giving this `td` element an ID. So "Text1" should have a background color of red at the end. I tried it like this, but this does not work.

```js
$("#test").parent().closest("td").css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>
    Text1
    </p>
  </td>
  <td id="test">
    <p>
    Text2
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8wyuggxz/

Comment: Title and Content seem contradictory. Title says *using id of a child element* whereas content says *without giving this `td` element an ID*.

Comment: with "this td element" i mean the td element which contains "Text1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method like following.

```js
$("#test").prev('td').css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                Text1
            </p>
        </td>
        <td id="test">
            <p>
                Text2
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx, but this solution is not what i search for, since i need to use the ID for my solution

Comment: One more question pls, what if i want to select the `p` element now? How can i do this? I tried `$("#test").prev('td').closest("p").css("background-color", "red");`

Comment: Use `find()` like `$("#test").prev('td').find("p").css("background-color", "red");` @EdwardBlack

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```js
$('td:contains("Text1")').css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        Text1
      </p>
    </td>
    <td id="test">
      <p>
        Text2
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure if OP is trying to select the second `td`. Content says this - *I try to select the td element which contains "Text1"*.

Comment: I try to select the td which contains "Text1", not "Text2"
I wrote: "So "Text1" should have a background color of red"

Comment: @EdwardBlack, That is just a matter of `string` you pass in `:contains`

Comment: Yes i know. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @RayonDabre Traverse from `td#test`

Comment: @JohnR, Did not get you ? OP is not asking to deal with index of the element but the content of the element...

Comment: @RayonDabre start from here...`$("#test")`

Comment: Question title `How to select first child of parent by using ID of a child element?`

Comment: @RayonDabre please check my answer. This what expected. And I upvoted you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : Here's a JS solution using the ID :

[See this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL8oexsL/1/)

```
$("#test").parent().find("td:first-child").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Thx, but this solution is not what i search for, since i need to use the ID for my solution

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$("#test").parent().children("td:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "red");
```

working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGMZYG

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to select first child of parent by using ID of a child element?
> 2. I try to select the td element which contains "Text1"

Solution for the both the queries.

**Code snippets:**

```
$("#test").parent().children('td:first:contains("Text1")').css("background-color", "red");
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8q1rty4e/1/)